# New Line in an Ansible String

Tags: ansible

I am running this Ansible playbook:

```
- name: Set String
  set_fact:
    string: item
  loop: "{{some_var|filter()}}"
  register: output

- name : Create a File
  copy:
    content: "{{string}}"
    dest: Path/test.txt
```

`some_var` is a JSON that comes from a previous task.

The variable `item` from the loop (executed only one time) contains this:

```
'test test\ntest test'
```

So `test.txt` file contains this:

```
test test\ntest test
```

I would like to get this content in the `test.txt` file:

```
test test 
test test
```

I believe I should modify the value that the filter returns. I don't know how.
Thanks

Comment: Can you replace `some_var`, `some_other_vars`, etc with real values? That is, can you update your question so that the sample code you present reproduces the problem you're asking about? Also, it looks like you're calling `set_fact` in a loop here, but you're discarding all but the last value in the loop.

Comment: yes, the loop it is executed only one time. it gest in input a `JSON` from another task and the output is a string similar to the one in the example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the literal block operator, `|`, like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Set String
      set_fact:
        string: |
          test test
          test test
      register: output

    - name : Create a File
      copy:
        content: "{{string}}"
        dest: test.txt
```

This results in:

```
$ cat test.txt
test test
test test
```

---

If the problem is that your variable contains the literal string `\n` and you want to turn that into a newline, just use the `replace` method:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    string: 'this is\na test'

  tasks:
    - copy:
        content: "{{ string }}"
        dest: file-without-newline.txt

    - copy:
        content: "{{ string.replace('\\n', '\n') }}"
        dest: file-with-newline.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. The string in the example comes from an Ansible filter. How do I format the string from the filter?

Comment: If you could update your question to show what you're actually doing, I'd be happy to try to update this answer.